# How to implement the 'tempfile' module to this code

Tags: python, urllib, temporary-files

This is a small widget that I am designing that is designed to 'browse' while circumventing proxy settings. I have been told on Code Review that it would be beneficial here, but am struggling to put it in with my program's current logic. Here is the code:

```
import urllib.request
import webbrowser
import os
import tempfile

location = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))

proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies=None)
opener = urllib.request.build_opener(proxy_handler)


def navigate(query):
    response = opener.open(query)
    html = response.read()
    return html

def parse(data):
    start = str(data)[2:-1]
    lines = start.split('\\n')
    return lines

while True:
    url = input("Path: ")
    raw_data = navigate(url)

    content = parse(raw_data)
    with open('cache.html', 'w') as f:
         f.writelines(content)

    webbrowser.open_new_tab(os.path.join(location, 'cache.html'))
```

Hopefully someone who has worked with these modules before can help me. The reason that I want to use tempfile is that my program gets raw html, parses it and stores it in a ***file***. This file is overwritten every time a new input comes in, and would ideally be deleted when the program stops running. Also, the file doesn't have to exist when the program initializes so it seems logical from that view also.

Comment: what do proxies have to do with tempfile? ... where are you even using  tempfile?  I would assume you want `proxy_handler = urllib.request.ProxyHandler(proxies={real_proxies})` ... other than that I dont understand what your question is ...

Comment: @JoranBeasley edited accordingly.

Comment: Is there a reason you can't just save `content` instead of writing it to a file?

Comment: that would make more sense to me as well ... but meh

Comment: @ford what do you mean? surely to save something it has to be a file??

Comment: why not just have a global content variable? then its saved as long as the programs running (as you asked) and it ceases to exist when the program stops running (again as asked) ... and you can easily overwrite it with new content as the program runs as well as read from it when appropriate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are passing the name of the file to `webbrowser.open_new_tab()`, you should use a [`NamedTemporaryFile`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tempfile.html#tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile)

```
cache = tempfile.NamedTemporaryFile()
...

cache.seek(0)
cache.writelines(bytes(line, 'UTF-8') for line in content)

cache.seek(0)
webbrowser.open_new_tab('file://' + cache.name)
```

Comment: I get an error saying that 'str does not support the buffer interface'. What do I do?

Comment: Didn't realize you were using python 3. See my edit.